# Change Detection for matDatepickerFilter in Angular datepicker

Tags: angular, angular-material, datepicker

I added a matDatepickerFilter to my material datepicker which works fine. When I open the datepicker, choose a date, close the datepicker and add the newly selected date to the filter array and open the picker again it is not filtered/greyed out. The filter only accepts the change after a reload. Is there a possibility to detect the changes?

Answer (score -1):

it is possible to provide some code snippets or more specific details about your implementation? That way, I can offer more accurate assistance in troubleshooting the issue you're experiencing with the matDatepickerFilter.

However, based on the information you've provided, it sounds like the filter array is not being updated or applied correctly when the datepicker is reopened. There could be a few potential reasons for this behavior. Here are a few suggestions to help identify and resolve the issue:

1. Verify that the filter array is being updated correctly: Double-check your code to ensure that the selected date is correctly added to the filter array when the datepicker is closed. Debugging or logging the values of the filter array before and after adding the selected date can help confirm if the update is occurring as expected.
2. Check the timing of the filter application: Make sure you are applying the filter to the matDatepicker correctly. It's possible that the filter is not being applied when the datepicker is reopened. Ensure that you are calling the filter function or applying the filtering logic at the appropriate time in your code.
3. Consider potential asynchronous issues: If the filter array is being updated asynchronously, there may be a delay in applying the filter to the datepicker. Ensure that the filter array is fully updated and ready before attempting to apply it to the datepicker.
4. Review the documentation and examples: Double-check the official Angular Material documentation and any relevant examples or guides for the matDatepickerFilter functionality. Compare your implementation against these resources to ensure you are following the recommended practices and conventions.

If the issue persists after trying these suggestions, please provide more specific details or code snippets related to your implementation, and I'll be happy to assist you further in resolving the issue.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! AI generated content is [currently banned](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831/20153035) on Stack Overflow. Please read the [AI Policy](/help/ai-policy) for more information.